como poner url (www.....com) a un archivo pagina web hecha con html en el bloc de notas
como poner url (www.nombredemipaginaweb.com) a archivo pagina web hecha con HTML en el bloc de notas .¿ con que etiquetas <...> ? ¿y en que parte del archivo html van :en head o style o body?

¿Cuál es la idea de colocar la URL? ¿Qué estás tratando de hacer?

La ruta de tu página web (si es eso lo que quieres hacer...) no se pone en el html... la ruta pertenece al servidor web que aloja el html, no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con el mismo. Una URL es una referencia a una IP nada más, en realidad. Es lo mismo navegar a www.google.es que navegar a la dirección IP de alguna de las máquinas que alojan su web. Si pretendes mostrar tu página web a otros, te recomiendo que empieces por aprender cómo funciona el alojamiento web y los servidores.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Sé que parece una pregunta tonta pero merece una respuesta. Para entender mejor el problema, te vendría bien tener conocimiento sobre servidores y redes.
La página que creaste es un archivo de código HTML. Para que otras personas puedan ver la página en internet necesitas un servidor.
El servidor tendrá una IP y estará pendiente a las solicitudes que los clientes le hagan. En respuesta devolverá el archivo HTML que creaste.
Para darle un nombre necesitas un dominio. Un dominio es único así que no podrás usar cualquiera. Tienes que elegir uno que no esté en uso.
Una vez que poseas el dominio y el servidor, debes configurar el dominio para que "apunte" al servidor. El proveedor podría brindarte diferentes métodos para realizarlo.

algunas referencias extra servidor , dominio y todo el como ligar/apuntar un dominio (nombre o url) a una ip ( computadora en internet o hosting ) sería DNS
